# tinyproxy dynamically allowing outgoing connections

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, tinyproxy

I am using tinyproxy in my project. I have requirement to add some domains in whitelist so that I can allow connections to listed domains only, I am using the feature of Tinyproxy that does filtering on domains specified in filter file.

This is as per https://tinyproxy.github.io/

Now I have a requirement that user can update the file with new domains or remove the existing domains from the file. So tinyproxy should dynamically take the updated file and restrict or allow the connections. I dont have to restart the service as I may be breaking some existing connections.

Is this possible to do in tinyproxy?

Answer (score 0):

You can reload the service instead of restart.
Realoding the service should keep the connection alive according to POSIX.
I know it works well for apache server but i am not sure how well it is implemented in tiny proxy.
You need to test it if you want to be sure.

Comment: I use it all the time with `tinyproxy 1.8.4` on `Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)`, Maybe it is not available on all version/distributions

Comment: service reload tinyproxy